# 401 login required error while displaying chart using easy dashboard javascript library

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I am displaying line chart using easy dashboard java script library.But it is throwing error 
401 login required.I created project in Google developer console and generated keys for it.
As 401 error code explains that credentials are wrong.Tell me what is the fault.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance
Here is the code for this

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head><title>GA Dash Demo</title></head>
<body>

  <!-- Add Google Analytics authorization button -->
  <button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">
        Authorize Analytics</button>

  <!-- Div element where the Line Chart will be placed -->
  <div id='line-chart-example'></div>

  <!-- Load all Google JS libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="gadash-1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=gadashInit" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        // Configure these parameters before you start.
    var API_KEY = 'AIzaSyA2LNhLKC4yvO9CmYXhp3tKjEvtd9GGZbc';
    var CLIENT_ID = '1096873113711-c8j9vt2ilnh6gbb0rshhfk3j89qv9pb5.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    var TABLE_ID = 'ga:91837123';
    // Format of table ID is ga:xxx where xxx is the profile ID.

    gadash.configKeys({
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'clientId': CLIENT_ID
    });

    // Create a new Chart that queries visitors for the last 30 days and plots
    // visualizes in a line chart.
    var chart1 = new gadash.Chart({
        'type': 'LineChart',
        'divContainer': 'line-chart-example',
        'last-n-days': 30,
        'query': {
            'ids': TABLE_ID,
            'metrics': 'ga:visitors',
            'dimensions': 'ga:date'
        },
        'chartOptions': {
            height: 600,
            title: 'Visits in January 2011',
            hAxis: { title: 'Date' },
            vAxis: { title: 'Visits' },
            curveType: 'function'
        }
    }).render();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you are missing the authentication.  Credentials are probably correct but you still need to request access.

Comment: how can i request access token

Comment: Any reason your not using the Embeded API for this?  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/

Comment: JavaScript Oauth2 documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent  Hello analytics JavaScript (really Old) https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api

Comment: it is very easy to use simple dashboard library.I want to display pie chart also.I had displayed graphs according to my need by using this.But unfortunately i deleted project in console.Now i created the project in the same way but this is not working

Comment: i did not use access token before and it was working fine

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm also experiencing this issue.